# On asp.net application end page view count data in not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I have asp.net application. I am forcibly end this application and on the time of that i want to update my view page count value in database. If anyone known plz help me.
I also written code in global.asax file

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Code that runs on application shut`enter code here`down
}
```

but this is not working when i forcibly end application.

Comment: Try using the `Application_Disposed` event.

Comment: I want to update page view counter data when application forcibly end and Application_Event will fired when application gracefully ends. i want to update data in both cases either application gracefully end or forcibly end

Comment: Try putting that code into `Application_Disposed` event and then check if its firing when application is forcibly closed.

Comment: May be this link will helps you,
  www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/what-is-use-of-globalasax-file-in.html

Comment: Hi Matt,   I tried Application_Dispose but not working it too .

Comment: Hello Neeraj , Already seen that but still finding solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer,

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Code that runs on application shut`enter code here`down
}
```

this event works only when the following things happens then fire.

1. Update web.config.
2. Update dll file in BIN.
3. Stop OR restart IIS.
4. Application pool recycle.

So i implemented a web service for this to update my records in database periodically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is a very idea to try to save the data upon exiting if it's important to you.

If you still want to try and you use .NET Framework 4.5.1, you can listen to the [`HostingEnvironment.StopListening`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment_events(v=vs.110).aspx) event, which fires when an application shut down is pending:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HostingEnvironment.StopListening += (o, args) => SaveTheDataHere();
}
```

This will save the data if the hosting environment is shut down in an orderly manner, not if it abruptly crashes.

Needless to say, this won't fire if there is a fire in the server room, a BSOD halts the OS, someone trips over a power cable, etc.

A better approach would be to offload the visit event (count) immediately or periodically (depending on what level of potential data loss i acceptable) to some error resilient external process, such as a message queue.